# Is There any ASTNode Library For IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, plugins, abstract-syntax-tree, intellij-plugin

Is there any library I can use on IntelliJ equivalent to org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom?

I want to be able to parse a java code to an AST.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The library is called the PSI. See [here](http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/architectural_overview/psi_files.html) for information about using the PSI.

Comment: I read about PSI but I don't understand exactly how is it equivalent to the dom library. does is have classes like "MethodDecleration" , "FieldDecleration" etc. ?

Comment: Yes. They are called PsiMethod, PsiField etc.